# Work table, error table and log table in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

What are the equivalent of the following Teradata tables in Snowflake:

- Work tables (WT)
- Error Tables(ET)
- UV tables- (another error table that stores data with uniqueness violations)
- Log Table(LT)

These tables get populated with Teradata TPT, is there an equivalent in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate analysis of the errors, a COPY INTO  statement then unloads the problematic records into a text file so they could be analyzed and fixed in the original data files. 
The statement queries the RESULT_SCAN table function to retrieve the records. Note that the statements in this section must be run in succession in order to retrieve the applicable records using the LAST_QUERY_ID function.

```
copy into mytable
  from @mystage/myfile.csv.gz
  validation_mode=return_all_errors;

set qid=last_query_id();

copy into @mystage/errors/load_errors.txt from (select rejected_record from table(result_scan($qid)));
```

Documentation reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-bulk-ts.html#step-2-validating-the-data-load

Comment: Thanks for the answer @FKayani. I am using `pyodbc` and running queries one after another, not sure if `set qid=last_query_id();` is valid? And instead of text, I believe I can copy it to the error table? Also, can you please add details on `WT`, `UV `, `LT` tables?